# Run random_ops in TensorFlow, TypeError happens

Tags: tensorflow

In RMSProp Optimizer `tensorflow\python\training\rmsprop.py`, I tried to introduce random noise to the algorithm.

So I invoked `rnd = random_ops.random_normal()` to return random values. But, when I run [training_ops.apply_rms_prop(...., rnd, ...).op](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/rmsprop.py#L103), `TypeError` happens:

> `TypeError: Input 'rnd' of Op requires l-value input`

Then tracing back to `TypeError` in [tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py#L558),

> `if not all(x.is_ref_dtype for x in types):`
>
> > `raise TypeError(`
> >
> > > `"Input '%s' of '%s' Op requires l-value input" % (input_name, op_type_name))`

I think it is because that the output of `random_ops.random_normal()` is not the reference type of `ApplyRMSProp Op`
. So my question is how to transform it to reference DType?

---

Note that in `tensorflow\python\training\rmsprop.py`, the arguments are transformed to non-reference DType

> `math_ops.cast(self._learning_rate_tensor, var.dtype.base_dtype)`

So maybe I can try `as_ref` function in `tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py`, like

> `math_ops.cast(rnd, var.dtype.as_ref)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`random_ops.random_normal()` returns an tensor, instead a `Variable object` the `training_ops.apply_rms_prop(...., rnd, ...).op` needs. So I import variables ops, by

> `from tensorflow.python.ops import variables`

and construct `rnd` of `Variable object`. After all, it works.